# I do not want my FireEvent function to return a boolean

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I do not want my Fire Event function in the following code to return a boolean. I think this can be done by removing the event listener but I am not sure how.

```
function FireEvent( ElementId, EventName ) 
{ 

if( document.getElementById(ElementId) != null ) 
{ 


if( document.getElementById( ElementId ).fireEvent ) 

{ document.getElementById( ElementId ).fireEvent( 'on' + EventName ); } 


else { 
var evObj = document.createEvent( 'Events' ); evObj.initEvent( EventName, true, false );     document.getElementById( ElementId ).dispatchEvent( evObj ); } } }
```

Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp
You can check this link

Comment: The function already does not return a boolean; it returns `undefined` because it's missing a `return` statement.

Comment: Yes but I think that dispatch event returns a boolean see this for reference http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent

Comment: That still doesn't return from *your* code.